# How to avoid users to manually install GDAL dependencies with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, dependencies, gdal

I know how to link GDAL with a C++ application using CMake. The procedure is summarized hereafter in two steps: (1) Installing the dependency on the system and (2) linking it to the C++ application (see [here](https://github.com/roshanpoudyal/Linux/wiki/How-to-link-GDAL-with-Cpp--application-using-CMake) for more details).

1. Install GDAL (here on Ubuntu 18.04)

   - Add the PPA to the sources: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`
   - Update: `sudo apt-get update`
   - Install GDAL and its development files: `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev`
   - Test the installation: `gdalinfo --version`
2. Link GDAL with the C++ application using CMake:

   ```
       # find system installed GDAL package with predefined CMake variable for finding GDAL
       find_package(GDAL REQUIRED)
       ...
       # Specify location of GDAL header files
       include_directories( include ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
       ...
       # Specify GDAL libraries to link your cpp executable target against
       target_link_libraries( your_cpp_executable_target_name ${GDAL_LIBRARIES})
   ```

What is the most convenient way to avoid the user to perform the manual installation of the dependency? That is, how to ensure that the missing dependency will not stop the configuration, and download/build the dependency if not found on the system?

For managing the Boost dependency, I used the CMake `ExternalProject` feature with a Superbuild pattern, and I think a similar approach should be relevant for managing GDAL dependency. However, I am very new at [modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/), and I struggle adapting [this CMake project handling the Boost dependency](https://github.com/dev-cafe/cmake-cookbook/tree/master/chapter-08/recipe-02) to also manage a GDAL dependency.

Any general or step-by-step directions to help doing (or good reasons not to do so) would be helpful.

Comment: If you don't want users to manually install dependencies, ship them yourself as part of your product. Then use the version that you ship rather than what the system provides.

Comment: *how to ensure that the missing dependency will not stop the configuration* - just omit `REQUIRED` magic word and ensure that this component is conditionally supported in your code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Do you suggest to copy-paste the whole dependency in my own project? I think I will do so for smaller dependencies, but for gdal and boost I was thinking about using the version provided by the system, or if not found downloading it and building it in the user's project.

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler More or less. That's what we do for a number of third party dependencies in the product I work on (which includes boost btw). We maintain a copy of each of them in our git repo (updated when it makes sense). Build them as part of building the product and ship them in our MSI and RPM packages that we deploy at customers. So we have complete control over what versions of dependencies we ship (including, in some cases our own patches to those). And when the customer installs the product they get *everything* they in one single package. It gets big (1.4G, but disk space is cheap).

Comment: @user7860670 it is a good answer to a wrongly worded question. I don't think I want to omit the REQUIRED word, as the user will be unable to perform the tests if the dependency is not met (see my previous comment)

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler We ship binaries though. Not source. But for source you can still do the same; include all dependencies in your repo.

Comment: So what are you asking exactly? It is a common knowledge that project dependency management and build setup has always been a major pain point for C++ development. So there is no "convenient way" to deal with it and "modern CMAKE" (btw what is modern about CMAKE?) won't be of much help.

Comment: @user7860670  If I understood well my lectures, the Superbuild Pattern is supposed to help dependency management. I'm trying to adapt [this cmake script](https://github.com/dev-cafe/cmake-cookbook/blob/master/chapter-08/recipe-02/cxx-example/external/upstream/boost/CMakeLists.txt) written for Boost to a Gdal case, but I just don't know how to proceed. See [Pablo Arias post](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) for a description of what is known as Modern Cmake.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I take good note of what your propose, and it will probably be my last resort option. However, the point of the question was more to adapt the superbuild pattern for GDAL, I will precise this in the question, thank you both for your help rephrasing it :)

Comment: That's the quirk with CMAKE - it has a lot of helpful macros for all kinds of needs, but it is not some kind of convenient build or dependency management system that works out of box. The linked CMAKE script - have you considered what will happen when you try to utilize some other project that utilizes different boost fetching script or when your project is used somewhere else? Amount of fragile boilerplate required to fetch boost even with help of ExternalProject is horrifying.

Comment: PS it could be a good idea to check [google depot tools](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/depottools). They have nothing to do with cmake, but at least it is an example of something that can be called a build / dependency management system.

Comment: @user7860670 thank you for your explanations. If I can rephrase what both of you said, I should abandon the perspective of the Superbuild (too fragile, too complicated) and either rely on the system (for Boost and Gdal) or include dependencies directly into the project. What I will probably end up doing :)